# how to mysql join works in my result

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables one  is tag_names  which is connected to TABLE groups by foreign key g_id.i fire 3 different select query with mysql JOIN and output is in fig(a)[image: fig(a)]

here table tag_names is:
[image: table tag_names]

**tell me please how mysql JOIN works in my result**

Comment: Please, no pictures. Just provide proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle.

Comment: If you want to know how (inner) join, left join, and right join differ, you could just consult an SQL book or online tutorial. Its not like they work differently "in my result" than anywhere else.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What result do you want? What is the second picture about ...

Comment: second picture have data entry which are gonig to be select

Answer (score 1):

Here's one good article about MySQL Joins: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

And keep in mind, when joining two tables on `g_id`, MySQL will result all the possible rows.

This result will give you all possible joins from both tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `tag_names` 
LEFT JOIN `groups` on `groups`.`g_id` = `tag_names`.`g_id` LIMIT 5
```

While this one will group both tables by `g_id`

```
SELECT * FROM `tag_names` 
LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`g_id` = `tag_names`.`g_id` GROUP BY `g_id` LIMIT 5
```